# How to cope up with "your subquery return more than one row"

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

Below is my query,

```
select * from user_details
where
  user_id in (
    select sender_id from pending_friend_request_table 
    where receiver_id=10
  )
```

Now I'm getting an obvious error that `'your subquery returns more than 1 row'`.

My question is, is there any way through which I can make the above query to work by using some MySQL keywords/functions like `range`, `limit`, `exists` etc or through some other methods.

Comment: Admittedly I don't know MySQL, but I don't understand why that query throws an error. The whole point of `IN` in every other flavour of SQL I know (SQL Server, DB2, and Oracle) is to handle multiple results from a subquery...

Comment: I fear you are not using `in` over the subquery but an `=` or something else. Check it. Otherwise, it seems, there is no issue.

Comment: With your last edit your question no longer makes sense. I will revert the last edit.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel okay, no issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to go with `JOINS`

```
SELECT * FROM user_details AS u
LEFT JOIN pending_friend_request_table AS p 
ON (u.user_id = p.sender_id)
WHERE p.receiver_id = 10;
```

Comment: by using "any" I'm getting only one of the row from pending_friend_request_table. I want to access all the possible rows from the pending_friend_request_table and display the rows from user_details accordingly

Comment: Please use JOINS instead of sub-queries. JOINS are much efficient then sub-queries.

Comment: can you please provide with some dummy data on SQLFIDDLE so that i can check there.

Comment: hey thanks but I'm not allowed to access the database.

Comment: But I'm sure that there are more than 1 row with the receiver_id=10

Comment: More than one row with single column is not a problem for IN clause at all. I don't know why are you facing this issue that's why i asked for some dummy data and structure. :)

Comment: Your join query works well but it is only fetching the result from the last row  times(number rows with receiver_id=10)

Comment: You can remove the WHERE condition to get all the results.

Comment: Sorry man your query was flawless, I just had messed up my Java code and thus wasn't getting the result